# Using iFrame on Flash website

Tags: flash, iframe

I am trying to add the a Facebook iFrame to my Flash website.  Since there is no real way to actually integrate the Facebook iFrame into the website, I was thinking of simply trying to overlay the iFrame on the Flash website.  This is done fairly easily from what I understand but have another issue.  I want to be able to disable the iFrame when I select a button on my Flash website.  Is this at all possible.  Any other routes I could consider?

Comment: This may be the most evil combination of web technologies I've read about =).

Comment: Yea, I know. I do all my websites in Flash but I have to find some way to add the Facebook Like Box to the website.  Kind of low on options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what want facebook "inside" your flash site, I would look into [flex-iframe](http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/).   I know that isn't the Facebook IFrame, but it doesn't allow interesting integration into your flash application, though I would require the flex framework if you are not currently using it.

Comment: Have you had any success of using this to embedd an iFrame in a Flash website?  I have been working with it but have not been able to figure too much of it out.  Thanks

Comment: the flex-iframe requires the flex 3 or 4 framework, i haven't tried it without, but yes I have gotten it to work quite well.  I year ago it had some issues in firefox, but my client was IE based so it was perfect, I think they may have solved the firefox issues now, but I'm not positive.

Comment: if your struggling with it ask on the mailing list :http://groups.google.com/group/flex-iframe